# How to calculate minimum in mule

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I want to calculate the minimum of 
vars.a , vars.b , vars.d-vars.c

```
min[vars.a,vars.b,vars.d-vars.c] is not working 

Math.min(Math.min(vars.a,vars.b),vars.d - vars.c) is also not working
```

I m trying to add this logic in a transform and I am using mule version 4.0

what is the best way to compute this is in mule ?

Comment: Check the docs for how to apply `min` to an array: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-min

Comment: Could you provide more context around which Mule version you are using and where are you trying to add that logic (an expression, a transform, an operation parameter)? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DataWeave you can calculate it as

```
min([vars.a,vars.b,vars.d - vars.c])
```

The parenthesis is missing in your code

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-min